# Use CanCan to define permissions additively

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

My application has 2 roles: Editor, and Admin. I want Editors to have some permissions, and Admins to have all editor permissions plus some other permissions.

Here is an excerpt from my `ability.rb`

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    if user.is_admin?
      can :edit, Post
    end

    if user.is_editor?
      can :edit, Post, :created_by_id => user.id
      can :read, Post
    end
  end
end
```

Since *all admins are also editors*, I hoped this would define these permissions:

- Admins can read and edit all posts
- Editors can read all posts, but only modify those which they created

However, CanCan doesn't seem to define permissions additively – i.e., when CanCan sees that a user is an Editor (even if the user is **also** an admin), it applies the more restrictive permission (i.e., `can :edit, Post, :created_by_id => user.id` instead of `can :edit, Post`).

Is there any way around this? The obvious solution requires repeating code:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    if user.is_admin?
      can :edit, Post
      can :read, Post # NOT DRY!!!
    elsif user.is_editor?
      can :edit, Post, :created_by_id => user.id
      can :read, Post
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried authorizing with a block?

```
can :edit, Post do |post|
 post.created_by_id == user.id || user.is_admin?
end

if user.is_editor?
  can :read, Post
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just redefine the edit alias?  You can also do:

```
can [:edit, :read], Post
```